# Socket io not receiving events after reconnection in rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

When the socket io client reconnects to server, I send an emit to the server in order to rejoin to all rooms that the socket been before he was disconnected.

But when sending events to this room where the socket supposed to be registered the client won't receive any event.

When sending to him individually, via the socket instance coming from the connection callback - everything is fine and he will receive the event.

Why does it happen?
The only way to make him receive the events again, is to completely force restart to the client (refresh the app).

I am using these on the server:

```
"socket.io": "^2.1.1",
"socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
```

and this on the client:

```
"socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
```

And in the server I am using the Redis adapter as follows:

```
var server      = require('@app/server');
var io          = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis       = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ 
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 6379
}));
io.set('origins', '*:*');

module.exports = io;
```

Maybe the problem is that the socket is actually joining to OLD rooms or an outdated node process or something like this?

Comment: When you reconnect to socket that client will have a different socket id from the old one

Comment: Yes but the room have the same name - I am sending to the room name

Comment: When you are sending an event to a particular room, that user has registered to that room with a old socket id and after reconnecting to socket, the old socket id is changed  right? so he won't receive the event

Comment: On first connection I join to room lets call it "A".
By the time the socket auto reconnects (after disconnection) I rejoin to all rooms, "A" as we mentioned.
Then from server I emit `io.to('A').event....` and the subscriber won't receive this message that he had received when he first connected.
I need to explicit tell the user to reload the client - and there he will connect and join room "A" successfully